# PSTerminalServices returning no details about session

Tags: powershell, rdp

I am connected to a machine using RDP but when I call the following (using PSTerminalServices via powershell):

```
get-tssession -computername thecomputer
```

I get:

```
Exception calling "GetSessions" with "0" argument(s): "No more data is available"
```

...instead of details of my session. It works great for virtual machines.

It is configured to allow remote assistance.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Get-TSSession` cmdlet tries to read some [registry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c55e734b-556d-44c5-a9df-a6c391991c54/remote-registry-query-error-no-more-data-is-available) (or [pipe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978797.aspx)?) data and fails. Looking at the `PSTerminalServices` source code I see that it uses [Cassia](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/) and this could be a [permissions issue](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/issues/detail?id=67).

This question may be relevant: [Calling WTSEnumerateSessions from a Local System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172796/calling-wtsenumeratesessions-from-a-local-system-service)

> Try to set on the remote server **'Full Control'** permissions for the
>   computer account of your machine and restart the Remote Desktop
>   Services service for the permission changes to take effect.

Comment: You're running as local admin, it's not the same. You have to set 'Full Control' permissions for you computer account (`YOURPCNAME$`) on the server. This image show computer account `TESTDOMAINDC$` in the security tab: http://support.citrix.com/article/html/images/1CTX134971-10.gif

Comment: Yeah I know but why is this not a problem when I connect to VMs on other machines?

Comment: I am a network administrator

Comment: Because this machine is a beautiful and unique snowflake? If you're really want to dig out _why_ it happens, start with monitoring `svchost.exe` instance that hosts Remote Desktop Services with Process Monitor.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Also, I will be stealing your dry comment about the snowflake and using it myself when the time is right. Cheers